# split table field value in HQL query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have field in table which contains multiple values separated by `;`.

I need to sort results by that field, but sorting must be made on minimal value of each field.

Is it possible to write something like this:

`ORDER BY MIN(SPLIT(";", FIELD)) ASC`

Comment: I am afraid whether this is possible even in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first select the all the values separated by ';' then use order by on that like.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(test_column,1,INSTR(test_column,'-')-1) as test_column
from TestTable order by min(test_column);
```